# generate multivariate data with different means

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate multivariate data, two outcomes (Y1 and Y2) that are correlated (with a given covariance) for a study that has 3 groups (a control group and 2 treatment groups) with each group having its own vector of means. Then, I want to loop over several studies (but I don't know how to do it because I have a very basic knowledge of R). Can someone help me how to improve the code I presented below?

```
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(1128)
sigma <-matrix(c(9,7.2,7.2,9),2)

(dat_Yc <-rmvnorm(n=1, mean=c(10,10),sigma=sigma, method="chol"))
(dat_Yt1 <-rmvnorm(n=1, mean=c(15,15),sigma=sigma, method="chol"))
(dat_Yt2 <-rmvnorm(n=1, mean=c(20,20),sigma=sigma, method="chol"))

study1 <- rbind(dat_Yc,dat_Yt1,dat_Yt2); study1
```

I know the above code is very simplistic and time-consuming especially when I want to loop it over k number of studies (say, k=20 or 40). Hope someone can suggest a better way to accomplish this task.

Comment: How are you looping over it? What timing are you experiencing and what timings are required? What lines are you looking to change? You don't have a lot of code here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to MrFlick's question. Apparently I cannot make a comment on his question so I wrote my reply here. Sorry.

I'm more interested in learning how to repeat the process of generating the data over a number of studies, say 20 or 40 studies, and then combine these data for meta-analysis. I'm not concerned about the timing or what not (or maybe I did not really understand your question considering that I just started learning R). Since I'm teaching myself how to do basic simulation, I wanted to know how I can make the code more efficient.

Comment: What is this?  It's definitely not an answer so it should not be here.  If you have a question, please write up a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a `list`. Which can be later used to retrieve individual results and its components. Hope this answers your question.

```
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(1128)
sigma <-matrix(c(9,7.2,7.2,9),2)
mean_c = c(10,10)
mean_t1 = c(15,15)
mean_t2 = c(20,20)
num.study = 20
study = vector('list', num.study)

for (i in seq_len(num.study)) {
  study[[i]] = list(dat_Yc = rmvnorm(1, mean_c, sigma),
                    dat_Yt1 = rmvnorm(1, mean_t1, sigma),
                    dat_Yt2 = rmvnorm(1, mean_t2, sigma))
}

## access the control group from 7th study
study[[7]]$dat_Yc
```